# Move App Data files to SDCard

Tags: android

I have an app which contain some images in `res/drawable/` and shows them in grid view.

I added some of my holiday pics to it so the size of my app increased to about **70MB** and bcoz its just a simple app, all of it get stored in the Phone memory and i want to change that.

So my problem is: How to make the app, so that after installing when i click **"Move to SDCard"** options, all the pics get stored on SDCard, and then are viewed in the app from there instead from phone memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put prefer external into your Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
... >
```

Comment: just that will make it to move all the images from drawable to sdcard??

Comment: it was giving installation error after that, but after changing it to **android:installLocation="auto"** its works fine, thnx.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the installLocation xml tag in Android Manifest file like it writes here: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html